# Can't locate Automake/Config.pm when trying to run aclocal command in OS X 10.7.4 x64

Tags: 64-bit, osx-lion, make

I am tring to compile the source code of libming 0.4.2 on Mac OS X 10.7.4 x64 and getting the following error when trying to run the `aclocal` command with sudo privileges:

```
$ sudo aclocal
Password:
Can't locate Automake/Config.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/bin/../share/automake-1.10
/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.12
/Network/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.12
/Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.3 /System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/System/Library/Perl/5.12 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12 .) at /usr/bin/aclocal line 43.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/aclocal line 43.
```

Xcode and Xcode command line tools are already installed in the system. I'm also able to compile the source on Mac OS X 10.6 i386.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following steps worked for me on OS X 10.7 x64:

1. Install [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org)
2. Enter the following commands one by one:

   ```
   sudo port install automake
   sudo port install autoconf
   sudo port install libtool
   sudo port install intltoo 
   sudo port install pkgconfig
   sudo port install cmake
   sudo glibtoolize --ltdl --force --copy
   sudo autoreconf
   ```
3. Build your code using the following commands:

   ```
   sudo ./configure
   sudo make
   sudo make install
   ```